# Converting String returned from Scanner nextLine() to String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

My requirement is that I need to convert a string input taken from a Scanner's nextLine() method, to a string array:

My code:

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
String myString = sc.nextLine();
```

The above code works fine, when I give input in the console as :  **new String[]{"A:22","D:3","C:4","A:-22"}**

but my challenge is to read scanner input and assign it to String array like this:

```
String[] consoleInput=sc.nextLine();
```

I have an incompatible type error, which is normal as String cannot be converted to String array. Is there a way to convert sc.nextLine() to String array in the above line?

Comment: what exactly are you expecting in the array?

Comment: I am expecting  **"A:22","D:3","C:4","A:-22"** from the input String **new String[]{"A:22","D:3","C:4","A:-22"}**

Comment: basically `myString.replaceFirst("^\\Qnew String[]{\"\\E","").replaceFirst("\\Q\"}\\E$","").split("\",\"", -1)` ? (assuming the quotes should NOT be included in the strings)

Answer (score 0):

If you literally type `n`, `e`, `w`,  , `S`, etcetera (you type in `new String[] {"A:22", "D:3"}` and you want a method on scanner such that you get a string with that data), that is incredibly complicated and involves linking a java compiler in. If you're asking this kind of question, likely well beyond your current skill level.

What you can do, however, is simply ask the user to enter something like:

> A:22 D:3 C:4 A:-22

Simply `.nextLine().split(" ")` and voila: First read a line, then split that line into a string array by looking for spaces as separators.

Comment: User wants exactly the same input as I have described, I have the solution for remaining all possible variants of the input. Thank you for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
String myString = sc.nextLine(); 

String[] arr = myString.replaceAll("[ \"{}]", "").split(",");
```

**Explanation:**
The regex in `replaceAll` replaces the characters `"`, `{`, '}`, and`  ` (space character) with an empty string. Then you simply split the string along all the commas, and you get a String array containing all the tokens the user entered.

**Note:** the regex removes all spaces as well, so if your tokens have spaces in them, then they will get removed. However, from what I gathered from your question, there won't be any spaces in the elements of the array.

Comment: Thank you. From my input string I need to extract only **"A:22","D:3","C:4","A:-22"**  Input String: **new String[]{"A:22","D:3","C:4","A:-22"}**

Answer (score 0):

Modified the regex pattern in `replaceAll()` method :

```
String[] strArr = s.nextLine().replaceAll("[ \"{}\\]\\[(new|String)]", "").split(",");
```

Output on printing the String Array strArr:

```
A:22 
D:3
C:4
A:-22
```